# Visual Format language (swift) for right alignmnent

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating text message kind of view and need a label in a cell,when I try to add constraint for right allignmetn it is not working,but for left it is working very well, could you help me find where the problem is?and how I can have a lable on the right side of my view?

I even try horizontal format string without '|' at the left part like this "[label]-10-|" but it did not work

```
func setMessage(right:Bool,text:String){

  //  var view:UIView =
    var lblText:UILabel = UILabel()
    lblText.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    lblText.text=text
    contentView.addSubview(lblText)
    contentView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    let views=["label":lblText]
    if(right){

        //
        let hConstraint=NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|[label]-10-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: views)
        lblText.backgroundColor=UIColor.redColor()
        contentView.addConstraints(hConstraint)

        let vConstraint=NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-25-[label]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: views)
        contentView.addConstraints(vConstraint)

    }else{


        let hConstraint=NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-10-[label(150)]-40-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: views)
        lblText.backgroundColor=UIColor.yellowColor()
        contentView.addConstraints(hConstraint)

        let vConstraint=NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-5-[label]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: views)
        contentView.addConstraints(vConstraint)
    }
```

Comment: Try removing `contentView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
`.

Comment: What is not working?  Of course, "|[label]-10-|"  won't work because that will stretch the label most of the width of the screen. What result did "[label]-10-|" give you? Be specific; "did not work" is not helpful.

Comment: @rdelmar well you are right, Sorry. it did not work means the constraint did not work and label was at the left of the cell.

Comment: @gabbler well thank you it did work, could you explain why removing that makes it work,

Comment: When you load a cell from nib, the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property of cell and cell.contentView are both set to YES, which are the default value and you don't change it, usually for the topmost views such as self.view you want this property to be YES, and to be NO for the subviews. For the contentView, if set to YES, the runtime will translate its autoresizing masks to auto layout constraints, which are called implicit constraints, so the contentView will pin its edges to its superview: the cell, the result is contentView has the same frame as the cell.

Comment: If you set it to NO, the contentView doesn't have constraints related to the cell, it will have the size of its subview, the size of the label, so you see the label is on the left. To fix this, you will have to add 4 explicit constraints to the cell, pin the edges of contentView to the cell to make it fill in the cell.

Comment: `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property of a view is YES, the default for a view if the view was created from code or loaded from a nib where "use auto layout" is not checked. If the view was initialised from a nib where "use auto layout" is checked, and the view is the topmost view, then this property of the view is YES, for all subviews of the view, this property is NO.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `if (right)` block horizontal constraints need a little tweaking. You'll need to specify the `H:` *without* the left bar (otherwise it'll align it to all superviews). `H:[label]-10-|` should do the trick.

```
if (right) {

    //
    let hConstraint=NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[label]-10-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: views)
    lblText.backgroundColor=UIColor.redColor()
    contentView.addConstraints(hConstraint)

    let vConstraint=NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-25-[label]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: views)
    contentView.addConstraints(vConstraint)

}
```

Comment: well I did try that ,but the label was still at the left, so as @gabbler said i removed  `contentView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)` and add constraint for my table view manually and it worked, thank you